# Deserializing Json String into multiple Object types

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a Json String that I get from a web service; it has a list of collections, each collection represents an object, for example:

```
  [ // Root List
    [ // First Collection : Team Object
      {
        "id": 1,
        "team_name": "Equipe Saidi",
        "is_active": true,
        "last_localisation_date": "2015-05-06T13:33:15+02:00"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "team_name": "Equipe Kamal",
        "is_active": true,
        "last_localisation_date": "2015-05-06T09:22:15+02:00"
      }
     ],
     [// Second Collection : user Object
      {
        "id": 1,
        "login": "khalil",
        "mobile_password": "####",
        "first_name": "Abdelali",
        "last_name": "KHALIL",
        "email": "KHALIL@gmail.com",
        "role": "DR",
        "is_active": true,
        "charge": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "login": "ilhami",
        "mobile_password": "####",
        "first_name": "Abdellah",
        "last_name": "ILHAMI",
        "email": "ILHAMI@gmail.com",
        "role": "DR",
        "is_active": true,
        "charge": false
      }
    ]
  ]
```

My actual code (not working of course ):

```
 public async Task TeamsAndMobileUsers()
    {
        string data = "";
        IList<User> MobileUsersList = new List<User>();
        IList<Team>  TeamsList  = new List<Team>();
        try
        {
            data = await GetResponse(PATH + TEAMS_USERS_URL);
            TeamsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Team>>(data);   
           MobileUsersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(data); 

            // Inserting
            await SetAchievedActions(TeamsList);

        }
        catch (Exception e) { 
            _errors.Add(e.Message); 
        }
    }
```

I use Json.net and C#. I can't find a solution, I've read that I should use JsonReader and set its SupportMultipleContent property to true but I don't know how to implement that solution.

Comment: Something is wrong with your JSON. It is invalid and incorrect in terms of logic. You have an array of two objects of different types. How do you want it to work together? Actually, they should be two objects. Are you able to edit JSON structure or receive it in another format?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433210/retrieve-the-values-from-json-string/). [Validate](http://jsonlint.com/), [generate class](http://json2csharp.com/) then `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(string json);`

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev No , i can't edit Json Structure :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As  @YeldarKurmangaliyev already said, your json has two different objects, I think you can do something like this:

```
var j = JArray.Parse(data);
TeamsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Team>>(j[1].ToString());
MobileUsersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(j[2].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried http://json2csharp.com/ to generate contract classes for that json? also, first and last parenthesis gives a not valid JSON

Comment: yeah you are right afer deleting the parenthesis, it passes JsonLint validation, but fails at Json2csharp generation .

Answer (score -4):

```
You need to create 4 classes
1st class TeamObject : Variable(id,team_name,is_active,last_localisation_date)
2nd class UserObject : Variable (id, login,mobile_password,first_name, last_name ,                        email, role,is_active,charge)
3rd class RootList: Variable ( arraylist<TeamObject> obj, arraylist<UserObject > obj2)
4th class RootClass : Variable(arraylist<RootList> obj)
Gson gson=new Gson();
RootClass dtomodel = gson.fromJson(data , RootClass .class);


This parsing done using Gson Library
```

Comment: Why Should I create 4 classes , knowing that i have two objects only user & team  !?. Gson is a java Library not c#.