# Deserializing Json String which is stored in a string variable

Tags: json

I am working in VS 2015 and c#.

I have a Json String which has a list of collections, each collection represents an object,

```
string wsjson = 
"{
"customAttributes":
    [{"description":"xxxxxxx","id":11,"value":"xxxxxxx"},{"description":"xxxxxxx","id":10,"value":"xxxxxxx"}],
"location":{"account":"xxxxxxx","cabinet":"xxxxxxx"},
"misc":{"approved":false,"archived":false,"deleted":false,"echo":true,"external":false,"favorite":false,"officialLocked":false,"signed":false},
"permissions":[{"xxxxxxx":true,"xxxxxxx":false,"edit":true,"noAccess":false,"share":true,"view":true}],
"standardAttributes":{"aclStatus":"xxxxxxx","created":"\/Date(xxxxxxx)\/","createdBy":"xxxxxxx","createdByGuid":"xxxxxxx","envId":"xxxxxxx","extension":"ndws","id":"xxxxxxx","modified":"\/Date(xxxxxxx)\/","modifiedBy":"xxxxxxx","modifiedByGuid":"xxxxxxx","name":"xxxxxxx","officialVer":1,"size":4,"syncMod":xxxxxxx,"url":"xxxxxxx","versions":1}}"

DataSet wsdataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(wsjson);
```

I am getting an error. I tried to follow this ([Deserializing Json String into multiple Object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593869/deserializing-json-string-into-multiple-object-types))  solution but I am getting error for this line as my jason data is in a string and no function to parse string.

```
var j = JArray.Parse(data);
```

Here is the visual image of the jason data.

[image]

Actual code block in my program is:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    string wsjson = GetWorkspaceProfile(row[0].ToString());                   
                    DataSet wsdataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(wsjson);
                    DataTable wsdataTable = wsdataSet.Tables["standardAttributes"];
                    foreach (DataRow wsrow in wsdataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        cmbWorkspaceByCabinet.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(row["envId"].ToString(), wsrow["name"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
```

Where GetWorkspaceProfile is a string type return function which return me JSON data as string like the image above.

```
public string GetWorkspaceProfile(string WorkspaceId)
        {
            string responseStr = "";
            string url = "v1/Workspace/" + WorkspaceId + "/info";

            RestType type = RestType.GET;
            Boolean useXml = false;
            RestRequest rr = FormRequest(type, url, useXml);
            IRestResponse response;
            try
            {
                response = executeRequest(rr);
                responseStr = response.Content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return null;
            }
            return responseStr;
        }
```

Comment: Unless they’ve changed their string lexing and parsing rules, that snippet doesn’t look like valid C#.

Comment: Hi Daniel: I just added the actual code block if you can help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JArray.Parse` will not work, because you don't have a json array, it is an object. Also not the all values of that object are collections, for example `location` is also object, not a collection. You have some options to parse it

1. Parse root object into `Dictionary`

   ```
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(wsjson)
   ```

   then parse every value of the dictionary to array if value is array and to dictionary if value is object.
2. Create a C# class according to your json data and parse string directly into instance of that class

   ```
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(wsjson);
   ```

   where `JsonModel` is the class you need to create.
3. You can use `JArray` and `JToken` to get the values you want using json path.

Comment: Hi Ruben, I just tried option 1 and getting this error:  Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'customAttributes', line 1, position 21.  this is how I used it: Dictionary<string, string> j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(wsjson); Can you please explain it little more if possible. thanks

Comment: for option 2: Would you be able to send me a sample class based on my scenario and how to use the class. thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1747541 try this stie http://json2csharp.com/ to generate c# model