# Easy Way to Transform JSON Response to C# string

Tags: c#, json

```
{"TrackPackagesResponse":{"successful":true,"passedLoggedInCheck":false,"errorList":[{"code":"0","message":"Request was successfully processed.","source":null,"rootCause":null}],"packageList":[{"trackingNbr":"478638332686","trackingQualifier":"2458500000\u007e478638332686\u007eFX","trackingCarrierCd":"FDXE","trackingCarrierDesc":"FedEx Express","displayTrackingNbr":"478638332686","shipperCmpnyName":"","shipperName":"","shipperAddr1":"","shipperAddr2":"","shipperCity":"Shaker Heights","shipperStateCD":"OH","shipperZip":"","shipperCntryCD":"US","shipperPhoneNbr":"","shippedBy":"","recipientCmpnyName":"","recipientName":"","recipientAddr1":"","recipientAddr2":"","recipientCity":"ROSWELL","recipientStateCD":"GA","recipientZip":"","recipientCntryCD":"US","recipientPhoneNbr":"","shippedTo":"","keyStatus":"Delivered","keyStatusCD":"DL","lastScanStatus":"","lastScanDateTime":"","receivedByNm":"B.CENESEY","subStatus":"Signed for by\u003a B.CENESEY","mainStatus":"","statusBarCD":"DL","shortStatus":"","shortStatusCD":"","statusLocationAddr1":"","statusLocationAddr2":"","statusLocationCity":"ROSWELL","statusLocationStateCD":"GA","statusLocationZip":"","statusLocationCntryCD":"US","statusWithDetails":"Delivered\u003a 1\u002f18\u002f2019 1\u003a39 pm Signed for by\u003aB.CENESEY\u003b ROSWELL, GA","halType":"","halCmpnyName":"","isHALAddress":false,"shipDt":"2019\u002d01\u002d16T00\u003a00\u003a00\u002d06\u003a00","displayShipDt":"1\u002f16\u002f2019","displayShipTm":"","displayShipDateTime":"1\u002f16\u002f2019","pickupDt":"2019\u002d01\u002d16T17\u003a51\u003a00\u002d05\u003a00","displayPickupDt":"1\u002f16\u002f2019","displayPickupTm":"5\u003a51 pm","displayPickupDateTime":"1\u002f16\u002f2019 5\u003a51 pm","estDeliveryDt":"","estDeliveryTm":"","displayEstDeliveryDt":"","displayEstDeliveryTm":"","displayEstDeliveryDateTime":"","actDeliveryDt":"2019\u002d01\u002d18T13\u003a39\u003a00\u002d05\u003a00","displayActDeliveryDt":"1\u002f18\u002f2019","displayActDeliveryTm":"1\u003a39 pm","displayActDeliveryDateTime":"1\u002f18\u002f2019 1\u003a39 pm","tenderedDt":"2019\u002d01\u002d16T17\u003a51\u003a00\u002d05\u003a00","displayTenderedDt":"1\u002f16\u002f2019","displayTenderedTm":"5\u003a51 pm","displayTenderedDateTime":"1\u002f16\u002f2019 5\u003a51 pm","apptDeliveryDt":"","displayApptDeliveryDt":"","displayApptDeliveryTm":"","displayApptDeliveryDateTime":"","nickName":"","note":"","matchedAccountList":[""],"fxfAdvanceETA":"","fxfAdvanceReason":"","fxfAdvanceStatusCode":"","fxfAdvanceStatusDesc":"","destLink":"","originLink":"","hasBillOfLadingImage":false,"hasBillPresentment":false,"signatureRequired":3,"totalKgsWgt":"0.45","displayTotalKgsWgt":"0.45 kgs","totalLbsWgt":"1.0","displayTotalLbsWgt":"1 lbs","displayTotalWgt":"1 lbs \u002f 0.45 kgs","pkgKgsWgt":"0.45","displayPkgKgsWgt":"0.45 kgs","pkgLbsWgt":"1.0","displayPkgLbsWgt":"1 lbs","displayPkgWgt":"1 lbs \u002f 0.45 kgs","totalDIMLbsWgt":"","displayTotalDIMLbsWgt":"","totalDIMKgsWgt":"","displayTotalDIMKgsWgt":"","displayTotalDIMWgt":"","dimensions":"8x5x4 in.","masterTrackingNbr":"","masterQualifier":"","masterCarrierCD":"","originalOutboundTrackingNbr":null,"originalOutboundQualifier":"","originalOutboundCarrierCD":"","invoiceNbrList":[""],"referenceList":[""],"doorTagNbrList":[""],"referenceDescList":[""],"purchaseOrderNbrList":[""],"billofLadingNbrList":[""],"shipperRefList":["172457"],"rmaList":[""],"deptNbrList":[""],"shipmentIdList":[""],"tcnList":[""],"partnerCarrierNbrList":[""],"hasAssociatedShipments":false,"hasAssociatedReturnShipments":false,"assocShpGrp":0,"drTgGrp":["0"],"associationInfoList":[{"trackingNumberInfo":{"trackingNumber":"","trackingQualifier":"","trackingCarrier":"","processingParameters":null},"associatedType":""}],"returnReason":"","returnRelationship":null,"skuItemUpcCdList":[""],"receiveQtyList":[""],"itemDescList":[""],"partNbrList":[""],"serviceCD":"FEDEX\u005f2\u005fDAY","serviceDesc":"FedEx 2Day","serviceShortDesc":"P\u002d2","packageType":"YOUR\u005fPACKAGING","packaging":"Your Packaging","clearanceDetailLink":"","showClearanceDetailLink":false,"manufactureCountryCDList":[""],"commodityCDList":[""],"commodityDescList":[""],"cerNbrList":[""],"cerComplaintCDList":[""],"cerComplaintDescList":[""],"cerEventDateList":[""],"displayCerEventDateList":[""],"totalPieces":"1","specialHandlingServicesList":["Deliver Weekday","Direct Signature Required"],"shipmentType":"","pkgContentDesc1":"","pkgContentDesc2":"","docAWBNbr":"","originalCharges":"","transportationCD":"","transportationDesc":"","dutiesAndTaxesCD":"","dutiesAndTaxesDesc":"","origPieceCount":"","destPieceCount":"","billNoteMsg":"","goodsClassificationCD":"","receipientAddrQty":"0","deliveryAttempt":"0","codReturnTrackNbr":"","returnMovementStatus":null,"scanEventList":[{"date":"2019\u002d01\u002d18","time":"13\u003a39\u003a00","gmtOffset":"\u002d05\u003a00","status":"Delivered","statusCD":"DL","scanLocation":"ROSWELL, GA","scanDetails":"","scanDetailsHtml":"","rtrnShprTrkNbr":"","isDelException":false,"isClearanceDelay":false,"isDelivered":true,"isException":false},{"date":"2019\u002d01\u002d18","time":"08\u003a24\u003a00","gmtOffset":"\u002d05\u003a00","status":"On FedEx vehicle for delivery","statusCD":"OD","scanLocation":"ALPHARETTA, GA","scanDetails":"","scanDetailsHtml":"","rtrnShprTrkNbr":"","isDelException":false,"isClearanceDelay":false,"isDelivered":false,"isException":false},{"date":"2019\u002d01\u002d18","time":"07\u003a59\u003a00","gmtOffset":"\u002d05\u003a00","status":"At local FedEx facility","statusCD":"AR","scanLocation":"ALPHARETTA, GA","scanDetails":"","scanDetailsHtml":"","rtrnShprTrkNbr":"","isDelException":false,"isClearanceDelay":false,"isDelivered":false,"isException":false},{"date":"2019\u002d01\u002d18","time":"02\u003a55\u003a00","gmtOffset":"\u002d05\u003a00","status":"At destination sort facility","statusCD":"AR","scanLocation":"ATLANTA, GA","scanDetails":"","scanDetailsHtml":"","rtrnShprTrkNbr":"","isDelException":false,"isClearanceDelay":false,"isDelivered":false,"isException":false},{"date":"2019\u002d01\u002d17","time":"16\u003a46\u003a00","gmtOffset":"\u002d05\u003a00","status":"Departed FedEx location","statusCD":"DP","scanLocation":"INDIANAPOLIS, IN","scanDetails":"","scanDetailsHtml":"","rtrnShprTrkNbr":"","isDelException":false,"isClearanceDelay":false,"isDelivered":false,"isException":false},{"date":"2019\u002d01\u002d16","time":"17\u003a51\u003a00","gmtOffset":"\u002d05\u003a00","status":"Picked up","statusCD":"PU","scanLocation":"MIDDLEBURG HEIGHTS, OH","scanDetails":"","scanDetailsHtml":"","rtrnShprTrkNbr":"","isDelException":false,"isClearanceDelay":false,"isDelivered":false,"isException":false},{"date":"2019\u002d01\u002d16","time":"14\u003a07\u003a31","gmtOffset":"\u002d06\u003a00","status":"Shipment information sent to FedEx","statusCD":"OC","scanLocation":"","scanDetails":"","scanDetailsHtml":"","rtrnShprTrkNbr":"","isDelException":false,"isClearanceDelay":false,"isDelivered":false,"isException":false}],"originAddr1":"","originAddr2":"","originCity":"MIDDLEBURG HEIGHTS","originStateCD":"OH","originZip":"","originCntryCD":"US","originLocationID":"","originTermCity":"MIDDLEBURG HEIGHTS","originTermStateCD":"OH","destLocationAddr1":"","destLocationAddr2":"","destLocationCity":"ALPHARETTA","destLocationStateCD":"GA","destLocationZip":"","destLocationCntryCD":"US","destLocationID":"","destLocationTermCity":"ALPHARETTA","destLocationTermStateCD":"GA","destAddr1":"","destAddr2":"","destCity":"ROSWELL","destStateCD":"GA","destZip":"","destCntryCD":"US","halAddr1":"","halAddr2":"","halCity":"","halStateCD":"","halZipCD":"","halCntryCD":"","actualDelAddrCity":"ROSWELL","actualDelAddrStateCD":"GA","actualDelAddrZipCD":"","actualDelAddrCntryCD":"US","totalTransitMiles":"","excepReasonList":[""],"excepActionList":[""],"exceptionReason":"","exceptionAction":"","statusDetailsList":[""],"trackErrCD":"","destTZ":"\u002d05\u003a00","originTZ":"\u002d05\u003a00","isMultiStat":"0","multiStatList":[{"multiPiec":"","multiTm":"","multiDispTm":"","multiSta":""}],"maskMessage":"","deliveryService":"","milestoDestination":"","terms":"Shipper","payorAcctNbr":"","meterNumber":"","originUbanizationCode":"","originCountryName":"","isOriginResidential":false,"halUrbanizationCD":"","halCountryName":"","actualDelAddrUrbanizationCD":"","actualDelAddrCountryName":"","destUrbanizationCD":"","destCountryName":"","delToDesc":"Receptionist\u002fFront Desk","recpShareID":"1kxjr88r627k1j0f9cqkginsm","shprShareID":"2amaeztp7591w1h1ckeddh6bc","requestedAppointmentInfoList":[{"spclInstructDesc":"","delivOptn":"","delivOptnStatus":"","reqApptWdw":"","reqApptDesc":"","rerouteTRKNbr":"","beginTm":"","endTm":""}],"defaultCDOType":"RTH","returnAuthorizationName":"","totalCustomsValueAmount":"","totalCustomsValueCurrency":"","packageInsuredValueAmount":"","packageInsuredValueCurrency":"","estDelTimeWindow":{"estDelTmWindowStart":"","estDelTmWindowEnd":"","displayEstDelTmWindowTmStart":"","displayEstDelTmWindowTmEnd":""},"standardTransitTimeWindow":{"stdTransitTimeStart":"","displayStdTransitTimeStart":"","stdTransitTimeEnd":"2019\u002d01\u002d18T16\u003a30\u003a00\u002d05\u003a00","displayStdTransitTimeEnd":"4\u003a30 pm"},"standardTransitDate":{"stdTransitDate":"2019\u002d01\u002d18T16\u003a30\u003a00\u002d05\u003a00","displayStdTransitDate":"1\u002f18\u002f2019"},"pkgDimIn":"8x5x4 in.","pkgDimCm":"20.32x12.7x10.16 cms","returnedToShipperTrackNbr":"","commodityInfoList":[{"countryOfManufacture":"","harmonizedCode":"","description":""}],"statusActionDesc":"","destinationGeoCoordinate":null,"serviceCommitMessage":"","serviceCommitMessageType":"","lastUpdateDestinationAddress":{"streetLineList":[],"city":"ROSWELL","stateOrProvinceCode":"GA","postalCode":"","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"addressVerificationId":"1kxjr88r627k1j0f9cqkginsm","shareId":null,"addressClassification":null,"addressClassificationConfidence":null,"classification":null,"urbanizationCode":null,"countryName":"United States","geographicCoordinates":null,"processingParameters":null},"halAddressLocationId":null,"streetGeoCoordinate":null,"isIndirectSignatureReleaseEligible":false,"isRerouteEligible":false,"isRescheduleEligible":false,"brokerName":"","brokerCompanyName":"","buyerSoldToPartyName":"","buyerSoldToPartyCompanyName":"","importerOfRecordCompanyName":"","importerOfRecordName":"","consolidationDetails":null,"exclusionReasonDetails":null,"piecesPerShipment":"1","totalPiecesPerMPSShipment":"0","fxfAdvanceNotice":true,"codrequired":false,"matched":false,"mpstype":"","rthavailableCD":"","excepReasonListNoInit":[""],"excepActionListNoInit":[""],"statusDetailsListNoInit":[""],"isExclusionReason":false,"isInvalid":false,"isNotFound":false,"isMultipleStop":false,"isCustomCritical":false,"isFedexOfficeOnlineOrders":false,"isFedexOfficeInStoreOrders":false,"isInTransit":false,"isOnSchedule":false,"isDelException":false,"isHAL":false,"isInProgress":true,"isShipPickupDtLabel":true,"isEstimatedDeliveryDtLabel":false,"isPrePickup":false,"isAnticipatedShipDtLabel":false,"isPickup":false,"isActualPickupLabel":false,"isClearanceDelay":false,"isDelivered":true,"isActualDeliveryDtLabel":true,"isDeliveryDtLabel":false,"isPending":false,"isExpiring":false,"isExpired":false,"isShipmentException":false,"isInFedExPossession":false,"isDroppedOff":false,"isOrderReceivedLabel":false,"isOrderCompleteLabel":false,"isDeliveryToday":false,"isBeforePossessionStatus":false,"isTenderedDtLabel":false,"isWatch":false,"isHistorical":false,"isTenderedNotification":false,"isDeliveredNotification":true,"isExceptionNotification":false,"isEstimatedDeliveryDateChangeNotification":false,"isCurrentStatusNotification":false,"isFSM":false,"isOutboundDirection":false,"isInboundDirection":false,"isThirdpartyDirection":false,"isUnknownDirection":false,"isFreight":false,"isSpod":true,"isSignatureAvailable":true,"isSignatureThumbnailAvailable":false,"isDocumentAvailable":false,"isMPS":false,"isGMPS":false,"isOriginalOutBound":false,"isReturn":false,"isCommodityInfoAvail":false,"isException":false,"isCanceled":false,"isSuccessful":true,"isCDOEligible":false,"isResidential":false,"isDestResidential":false,"isDuplicate":false,"isSave":false,"isMtchdByRecShrID":false,"isMtchdByShiprShrID":false,"CDOExists":false,"isHalEligible":false,"isReqEstDelDt":false,"CDOInfoList":[{"spclInstructDesc":"","delivOptn":"","delivOptnStatus":"","reqApptWdw":"","reqApptDesc":"","rerouteTRKNbr":"","beginTm":"","endTm":""}],"isEstDelTmWindowLabel":false,"isHistoricalEDTW":false,"isNonHistoricalEDTW":false,"isTargetedMsg":false,"isStreetMapEligible":false,"isConsolidationDetail":false,"errorList":[{"code":"","message":"","source":null,"rootCause":null}],"isShipDtLabel":false,"isHALResidential":false,"isActualDelAddrResidential":false,"isChildPackage":false,"isParentPackage":false,"isReclassifiedAsSingleShipment":false,"isMaskShipper":false}],"alerts":null,"cxsalerts":null}}
```

Is there any easy way to add escapes to this response so that I can make it a valid c# string?

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471842/4822855? It seems that there are some questions about the same argument.

Comment: I always just replace the " with ' and then put "" around the entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://json2csharp.com for JSON to C# models...

After then you can parse that by Json.NET - Newtonsoft https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score -1):

To convert any text to C#/JavaScript/C/Java string constant you can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) Text Wizard -> To JS String functionality.

Note that while it is useful for some tests it may be better to construct anonymous (or even strongly typed) object and serialize it to JSON string- [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)