# How to interpret JSON in c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to add cat facts to my discord bot (Not relevant) and the site i use returns a json that goes something like this:

```
{
  "facts": ["The fact is here"], 
  "success": "true"
}
```

The site is http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts
I would just like to grab the fact as a string.

The Following is what i am currently using but messes up when the fact contains '"'

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string thingy = wc.DownloadString("http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts");
string[] thingys = thingy.Split('"');
string fact = thingys[3];
```

Comment: Take a look at Newtonsoft.Json lib.

Comment: Use `Netwonsoft.Json` to deserialize your JSON string into a C# object. Also look at http://json2csharp.com/.

Comment: have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433210/retrieve-the-values-from-json-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Newtonsoft.json nuget package to your project may help you `deserialize` the json to the appropriate `Class` or if you are reading just a couple of properties you could use `JObject` available as part of the same library.

Document : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Here is a sample

```
  using Newtonsoft.json;
  Class Cats
  {
    string[] Facts {get; set;}
  } 

  var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
  var response= wc.DownloadString("http://catfactsapi.appspot.com/api/facts");
  var cat = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Cat>(response); 
  // Access facts
  if(cat !=null && car.Facts!= null)
  {
       foreach(var fact in car.Facts)
       {
       }
  }
```

**Alternatively**
if there are only a couple of properties

```
  var catObj = JObject.Parse(response);
  var facts = catObj["Facts"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(thingy);
string fact = parsedJson.facts[0];
```

This parses the json into a dynamic object and reads the fact field which is an array. The first element of the array contains the one fact there is.

If there are many facts you can iterate the parsedJson.facts which is a string array